# Filter and Order a multi-dimensional array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

Given the following array in JavaScript:

```
_articles = [{ id: 0, name: 'aaa', category: 1, date: '2021-05-17'}, { id: 1, name: 'bbb', category: 3, date: '2021-03-15'}, { id: 0, name: 'ccc', category: 2, date: '2021-02-11'}, { id: 0, name: 'ddd', category: 1, date: '2021-04-11'}]
```

How can be **filtered by category=2 and sorted by date** (recent first)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
let filtered = _articles.filter(x=> x.category=2)
```

and the sort DESC

```
let sorted =_articles.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.date)-new Date(a.date))
```